# Python ctypes and char**

Tags: python, ctypes

I have the following structures in C:

```
struct wordSynonym
{
    wchar_t* word;
    char** synonyms;
    int numSynonyms;
};

struct wordList
{
    wordSynonym* wordSynonyms;
    int numWords;
};
```

And, I have the following in Python:

```
class wordSynonym(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ("word", c_wchar_p),
                  ("synonyms", POINTER(c_char_p)), # Is this correct?
                  ("numSynonyms", c_int) ];

class WordList(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ("wordSynonyms", POINTER(wordSynonym)),
                 ("numWords", c_int)];
```

What is the correct way to reference `char**` in python?  That is, in the Python code, is `POINTER(c_char_p)` correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this in my code:

```
POINTER(POINTER(c_char))
```

But I think both are equivalent.

**Edit:**
Actually they are not
http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p

> ctypes.c_char_p 
>   Represents the C char * datatype when it points to a zero-terminated
>   string. **For a general character pointer that may also point to binary
>   data, POINTER(c_char)** must be used. The constructor accepts an integer
>   address, or a string.

So `POINTER(POINTER(c_char))` is for binary data, and `POINTER(c_char_p)` is a pointer to a C null-terminated string.

Comment: For example: `c_char_p('sp\x00am').value == 'sp'` and `(c_char*5).from_buffer_copy('sp\x00am').raw == 'sp\x00am'`. It also has a `value` attribute that returns the string up to the first NULL (else the whole array).